What is XX一行 in English?
This expression can often be seen in news report such as “XX一行参观了学校校园并与师生进行了交流”. In some reports in English made by Chinese writers or translators, the 一行 is put as “his delegation" "the group" "his team" or things like that, but I never see such usage in the similar context in news media of native speakers of English.
Most of the media would only mention the person who pays the visit and the assistants, aides, body guards, secretary or other people are ignored, but a delegation or a team of many people is hinted.
So what is the 一行 in English?

maybe entourage  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/entourage

maybe retinue ?

Another alternative: XX and his/her delegation

一行 - 一群同行的人 (group of people travelling together; party; delegation)

xx一行 = xx和同行人員 (XX and the persons who are traveling with him together.

